# Where is 3D view in Firefox firebug?

Tags: firefox, browser, firebug

I can not find 3D view of webpage in firebug. How do I enable it? I am using firefox 21.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 3D view is a feature of the default inspector. It's not present in Firebug.

Comment: And to get it going in the default inspector, see http://superuser.com/a/405300/197108

Comment: With Firefox version 47 the 3D was removed :-(